# Register with Geodatabase greyed out

Tags: arcgis-desktop, enterprise-geodatabase, esri-geodatabase, table, database

I'm having trouble registering a table with a Geodatabase in an SDE, the option is greyed out. This is a weekly task for me and I have never had this happen before.

I receive a new table weekly from our accounts department and have to check if there is any new entities in it to add to my parcel database. When I right click on the table and go to mange the option to register with database is greyed out.

I checked for locks on the table and there are none. I previewed the table and it appears to be the same as every week

I am the only one working off the database at the moment, has anyone run into similar problems before? Any suggestions on things to try?

Comment: try using the register with enterprise geodatabase geoprocessing tool. Read the error message in the gp results messages.

Answer (score 1):

Well in the end it was completely user error. After geoprocessing the table every week I need to delete it, for whatever reason I forgot to delete the table the previous week meaning it was still registered with the geodatabase.

In the end I deleted the table and will have to wait till next week to run the scripts on it!

Thanks